# How to get every line of instruction for invoking method using Reflection C#

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am working in Reflection C#.

My requirement is specified method is invoke using reflection, getting following
things from invoking method after method invoked.

1. Comment line
2. Executing instruction in method

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible. Reflection is not about instrumentation. You can't get comments from it also. It is also very interesting - for what do you need such information?

Comment: The comment line? Those are not compiled into an assembly. Who gives you that taks? The executing instruction could be possible by decompilation or analyzing the MSIL, but not via Reflection.

Comment: There are APIs to get call stacks.  Not sure what you are looking for here.  In visual studio you can use automation to get CodeClass and CodeFunction.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the `summary` xml information?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not possible because reflection is not the holy grail which can decompile your assemblies.

It's so that programs written in .NET (Vb, C#, ...) or compiled to IL or Intermediate Language.

**So, what's the Intermediate Language?**

Intermediate language (IL) is an object-oriented programming language designed to be used by compilers for the .NET Framework before static or dynamic compilation to machine code. The IL is used by the .NET Framework to generate machine-independent code as the output of compilation of the source code written in any .NET programming language.

IL is a stack-based assembly language that gets converted to bytecode during execution of a virtual machine. It is defined by the common language infrastructure (CLI) specification. As IL is used for automatic generation of compiled code, there is no need to learn its syntax.

This term is also known as Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) or common intermediate language (CIL).

***Example:***

Let's have a look at the following mini application:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    // Start class.
    class Program
    {
        // Main entry point.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
   }
```

}

When you now use a took such as Telerik JustDecompile, you can view the source code of the application:

using System;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the code the decompiler produces is in fact different than what you had originally, however it's the same technical.

But a public constructor is added (even when you don't add one in your class, the compiler add's a default one). 
The comments are gone.

Now, why is this? This is because the compiled exe file does not contain your code, but does just contain your code translated into IL and it's the IL which the decompiler will translate back to C#.

So, how does that IL looks like?

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication1.Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor () cil  managed 
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static void Main (
            string[] args
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .entrypoint
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldstr "Hello, World!"
        IL_0006: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_000b: nop
        IL_000c: ret
    }
}
```

You see this is already something which is more close to machine language.

So, I hope this makes clear why you cannot get your source code through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Reflection is not about instrumentation, it is about metadata describing types, methods etc. You can't get comments from it also as they are not included into compiled assemblies.

In fact, such deep insight into running assembly is not possible at all without very very magic, like using `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime`:

> ClrMD is a set of advanced APIs for programmatically inspecting a crash dump of a .NET program much in the same way as the SOS Debugging Extensions (SOS). It allows you to write automated crash analysis for your applications and automate many common debugger tasks.

Is is also possible to attach to self process and analyze it during normal work, so **maybe** it would be possible to get some information about instrumentation. But as I say - this would be magic. And I am sure, you do not need to do that at all.